# gtk# don't show the window on the task bar

Tags: c#, gtk, gtk3, gtk#

Is it possible to not show the window in the task bar using GTK windows?

I found some solutions on Internet that I tried but that do not work with GTK 3.24

I read the GTK documentation but I didn't find that feature. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

TypeHint = WindowTypeHint.Utility;